# iOS - Error when adding row to UITable (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting this error when adding a row to a UITable.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 7.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

number of elements:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            return mArray[section];
        }
        return 1; // only top row showing
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

Counting number to be in each part:

```
                int k = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                    if ([[currentEntry objectForKey:@"item"] isEqualToString:items[i]]) {
                        mArray[i] += 1;
                        k = i;
                    }
                }
```

Adding to table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];


            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {

                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                NSLog(@"SSection:%d", rows);
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];

                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                });
            }
```

Error occurs here

```
else
            {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                  });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error only occurs in one section which is 7. All other sections are fine

Comment: update your question with insert row code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need add object in collection which telling tableview about count of items for appearing, create index path for new cell and make insert row with index path. Perhaps you create wrong index path.

Comment: He's right, i think youre not adding the item to the mArray

Answer (score 0):

I think your `array` and your `numberOfRows` should be matching in your 7th section.

```
//MARK: UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 7) {

    return YOUR_ARRAY.count;
 }
}
```